# Area Lemma + Menelaus Theorem

Tags: geometry, area

- $In ∆ABC , AB = AC = 115, AD = 38,\ and \ CF = 77\; where\; D \; lies\; on \; AB \;  and  \; F \; lies \; on \; AC \;  produced. \; DF \; intersects \; BC \; at \; E. \;
   Compute \; {[CEF]\over [DBE]}  .$

This question is from Pathfinder For Olympiad Mathematics.

I tried solving this question by Base Division Theorem: by finding ratio between DE and FE, but got stuck in the beginning.
I then thought of Menelaus, but I am confused in which triangle I should apply, and which line to take a s Menelaus Line.
Here's what I did:

- Menelaus, $\frac{CE}{CB} \cdot \frac{AB}{AD} \cdot \frac{DF}{FE}=1$, so $\frac{CE}{CB} \cdot \frac{DF}{FE}=\frac{38}{115}$. Let $\frac{CE}{CB}=\frac{2}{5}, \frac{DF}{FE}=\frac{19}{23}$. From the sine area formula the ratio of the areas is just $\frac{CE \cdot EF}{EB \cdot ED}$. We have $\frac{CE}{EB}=\frac{2}{7}$ and $\frac{EF}{ED}=\frac{23}{42}$, so multiplying gives $\boxed{\frac{23}{147}}$. Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Any help will be much appreciated.

NOTE:I have already asked this question in the forum, but somehow it got closed. And as I didn't get a answer, I am asking it again, this time with more clarifications and my attempt. Will this question get closed?

Comment: Since $AD=38$ and $AF=115-77=38$, don't we have $\Delta ADF\sim\Delta ABC\implies DF|| BC$?

Comment: *$ AF = 115+77 $

Comment: Ok, I have never heard of this produced terminology.

Comment: You already posted this question: it was closed but now it's open again and it had a good answer. See also my comment there.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Yes, it was reopened when I posted this one. Now shall I delete this one?

Comment: You can delete it if you want.